# Global Transaction Timeout for Spring HibernateTransactionManager

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions

I am using Spring's HibernateTransactionManager to manage my transactions using annotations. It looks like timeout values can be set on annotations, but i dont see how to set them globally for the whole application and then override on the annotation on a need basis.

Here is my configuration

```
<bean id="txManager"     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
```

Any ideas? thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HibernateTransactionManager.setDefaultTimeout()`:

```
<bean id="txManager"     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name = "defaultTimeout" value = "value in milliseconds" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```